# How to handle Optional Grammar Blocks with a ANTLR-Visitor?

Tags: antlr4, option-type, visitor-pattern

It is possible that this question has been asked before but i cannot find it. So if you guys find something similar, please let me know.

According to the following Rule:

```
fix_body : ident  binders (annotation)? (':' term)? ':=' fix_body_term;
```

I have an optional annotation and an optional Term. The corresponding visitorRule looks like this :

```
public FixBody visitFix_body(coqParser.Fix_bodyContext ctx)
```

My Question is how do i find out, if there was a term or not?

There is a method for reaching the term by using `ctx.term()`, but when there is no term given, does this method return `null`? Or is there a completly different way to approach this? As i am working with a large grammer it will take me a while to test this, otherwise I would have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trap there ...

If the term is optional, you just have to test it before calling the `accept(visitor)` method

In your case

```
if(ctx.term() != null) ctx.term().accept(new TermVisitor())
```

Example:

- [Optional in a grammar](https://github.com/yafred/asn1-tool/blob/v0.0.14/grammar/src/main/antlr4/com/yafred/asn1/grammar/ASN.g4#L49)
- [Testing before accepting the visitor](https://github.com/yafred/asn1-tool/blob/v0.0.14/model/src/main/java/com/yafred/asn1/parser/SpecificationAntlrVisitor.java#L184)

Comment: Ok this is good to know. However just to clarify. It seems for me that there is no difference between ctx.term().accept(new TermVisitor()) and (new TermVisitor()).visit(ctx.term()). Am i right?

Comment: I think you're right. It's all design pattern stuff. I was used to the accept() method and ANTLR provides it, so I used it (it is called visitor pattern double dispatch method apparently). if you're more comfortable with visit(), go for it.